# Wicket: AjaxRequestTarget vs onModelChanged

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I'm working on a code in a wicket project, where the original devs used the `onModelChanged()` method quite a lot in Ajax request handling methods. I, for one, however am not a strong believer of this implementation.

In fact, I can't think of any examples, where calling the `target.add(...)` is inferior to calling the onModelChanged method.

Am I missing some key concepts here?

Example:

```
public MyComponent extends Panel {

    public MyComponent(String id, Component... componentsToRefresh) {

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("someId") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                // some logic with model change

                for(Component c: componentsToRefresh) {
                    c.modelChanged();
                }

                target.add(componentsToRefresh);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, there are a couple of things I don't agree with, the very first is the componentsToRefresh parameter, the second is (as the question suggests), the fact that we called `c.modelChanged()` on all components in that array. My guess would be that it is completely un necessary and instead of a parameter in the constructor, one should just write an empty function in `MyComponent` and override it, and put the necessary components in there when needed.

Comment: Can you please give some more details how `onModelChanged()` is being used in this application ? I don't quite see the relation with `target.add(...)`.

Comment: edited original question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Wicket Event system instead. That is, whenever the AjaxLink is clicked you will broadcast an event:

```
send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREATH, new MyEventPayload(target));
```

This will broadcast the event to the current Page and all its components.

Then in any of your components you can listen for events:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(IEvent event) {
  Object payload = event.getPayload();
  if (payload instanceof MyEventPayload) {
    ((MyEventPayload) payload).getTarget().add(this); // or any of my sub-components
    event.stop(); // optionally you can stop the broadcasting
  }
}
```

This way you do not couple unrelated components in your application.

See [Wicket Guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_wicket_events_infrastructure) for more information.

Comment: that is waaaay too heavy for just a click of a button, or some string in a textfield

Comment: Agreed! If you need to update just a few components which are siblings of the Ajax component then you can just provide overridable `onSomeEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target)` and use it in the caller/parent. But if you need to update components elsewhere on the page then using Wicket Event system is recommended. It scales better and there is no coupling between the components.